# Why does ActiveRecord Timezone return -03:00 timezone when you try to create a -4 timezone with ActiveSupport?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All the other timezones appear to work fine, except the -4 one

```
(byebug) event.start_at.in_time_zone(-5)
Sun, 09 Aug 2020 05:00:00 -05 -05:00

** This call **
(byebug) event.start_at.in_time_zone(-4)

Sun, 09 Aug 2020 07:00:00 ADT -03:00
(byebug) event.start_at.in_time_zone(-3)
Sun, 09 Aug 2020 07:00:00 -03 -03:00
(byebug) event.start_at.in_time_zone(-2)
Sun, 09 Aug 2020 08:00:00 -02 -02:00
(byebug) event.start_at.in_time_zone(-6)
Sun, 09 Aug 2020 04:00:00 CST -06:00
(byebug) event.start_at.in_time_zone(-7)
Sun, 09 Aug 2020 03:00:00 MST -07:00
(byebug) event.start_at.in_time_zone(-8)
Sun, 09 Aug 2020 03:00:00 PDT -07:00
(byebug) event.start_at.in_time_zone(-9)
Sun, 09 Aug 2020 02:00:00 AKDT -08:00
```

it's not even consistent in its own implementation

```
2.6.6 :005 > Time.now.zone
 => "EDT" 
2.6.6 :006 > Time.now.in_time_zone(-4)
 => Tue, 11 Aug 2020 12:03:55 ADT -03:00
```

note: EDT is the correct timezone during the summer, although who knows what would happen if I wasn't in North America. But ADT-03:00 is not the correct timezone for the East coast in either summer or winter.

So basically it is assuming that the timezone is not seasonally adjusted, but only for the East coast of America, not any other location. WTF!?

Comment: I can confirm this, it seems to be converting to ADT which is Atlantic Day Time

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is adjusting to Daylight Saving

```
2.6.5 :023 > Time.now.in_time_zone(-4)
 => Mon, 10 Aug 2020 01:07:47 ADT -03:00 
2.6.5 :024 > (Time.now + 3.months).in_time_zone(-4)
 => Tue, 10 Nov 2020 00:08:03 AST -04:00 
2.6.5 :025 >
```

You can see in this example.
Currently Daylight saving is on hence `-4` shows `ADT -03:00`
On November 1, 2020 Daylight Saving is ending.
So 3 months (on November 10, 2020) `-4` shows `AST -4:00`

Comment: but DST is regional and I've already accounted for the DST. Why/how would the Ruby interpreter try to figure out of DST in effect given an offset? IF I tell the Ruby interpreter Time.now.in_time_zone(-8) for MST, how would it know if I was standing in Arizona, where DST is not observed but is in the MST timezone?

Comment: the problem here is that ```Time.now.in_time_zone``` is functionally useless because of this, and it's annoying a problem specific to the East-coast of the United States (and the same for the South American hemisphere in the -5 timezone too). Leave it to the international people to mess up the Americans timezones. (I realize how messed up DST is to begin with but this is literally nonsense… I spent at least 2 days taking the timezones apart and putting them back together again only to learn that `.in_time_zone` in Ruby is useless.)

Comment: Yes @JasonFB Your question is valid. 
I have already dug deep into checking how `in_time_zone` method work. So it internally calls some methods which includes `find_zone` and when you provide input like `-4` there are 4 timezones and the first one is returned.
If you want a specific then you need to provide the timezone name instead of offset.

Comment: There is a nice blog about practices to deal with timezones. This might help you.
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones

Comment: as a result of this implementation, I literally had an interface where each time I clicked the "Update" button - without making a change- my time would decrement by 1 hour. the real heart of the issue is that user's don't expect to *pass* an adjusted timezone, or have to *do the math* themselves to figure out how to adjust the time. They just want it in their own timezone and for the computer to do the rest of the work.... If I call `Time.now.in_time_zone(-4)` I expect it to either return `AST -04:00` or `EDT -04:00` (either is valid), but NOT `ADT -03:00` — that's the WRONG timezone!

Comment: IMHO, a computer should either know a date or timezone is adjusted for DST, or that *it isn't*. The only way to actually do it right is to know where the user is and if they are in a region that observes DST. The problem with the `Time.now.in_time_zone` is that it tries to *guess* which is the problem

Comment: I think you can check TZinfo gem. It may have access to platform specific system level library interfacing. So you can save time in UTC in DB and while accessing you may convert it to the timezone that you receive from system. I haven't tried this. But sounds like a good food for thought. Will see if I could do something on this weekend.

Comment: @JasonFB Do let me know what solution works for you. I would be interested to know.

Comment: sadly, my solution was "don't use `.in_time_zone`" I will check out the TZInfo gem that looks promising! All I really need are a few utilities to manipulate time with given timezones (it's all for user-centric display of course), and I was frustrated with the default stuff in Ruby and Rails

Comment: If it's a user-centric display, then how about asking user to set their preferred timezone (may be) in profile? And then using that timezone everywhere. 
But again from the examples, I would suggest not to pass offset to `in_time_zone` instead use timezone name

Comment: ahh. yes what you describe is my exact implementation. But how do you take the timezone — which is stored in a numeric offset from UTC, and convert that into a "ActiveRecord::Timezone" object? I can find no place in the API to convert from an offset to something that this `.in_time_zone` ActiveRecord object will accept. I guess my problem is that I think it should accept integers but it seems to want to accept strings.

Comment: I guess when I say "user centric" i mean in the summer I want someone on the East coast to answer "Eastern" and mean EDT (which is -4) and in the winter I want someone the East coast to also answer "Eastern" and mean EST (which is -5), so … like it's user centric but I don't want to bother the user with the nuance of knowing whether it is daylight savings now (summer vs. winter) or in their state (Arizon & Hawaii vs the other 48 states that observe DST)…